# spring security work only for highest priority order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to integrate spring mvc in existing spring rest project. Security for spring rest is working fine. When I tried to implement security for spring mvc with least priority order then it will only worked for rest api. If I have set priority order for spring mvc high then it will work for spring mvc but for rest api it will redirect to login page.

Here is my code snippet

```
//base class for spring security config
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig
```

I have a two static class

for spring mvc

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

for rest api

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public static class ApiSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

For spring mvc configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home",true)

                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
}
```

For Rest api configuration

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
                .csrf().disable()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

                // don't create session
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

                .authorizeRequests()

                // Un-secure H2 Database
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/refresh/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/facebook/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(userDetailsService(), jwtTokenUtil, tokenHeader);
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  // required to set for H2 else H2 Console will be blank.
                .cacheControl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // AuthenticationTokenFilter will ignore the below paths
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        authenticationPath)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                        refresh)
                // allow anonymous resource requests
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/*.js",
                        "/*.*.*",
                        "/**/**/*.*",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/resources/**",
                        "/static/**"
                )

                // Un-secure H2 Database (for testing purposes, H2 console shouldn't be unprotected in production)
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` basically configures one `SecurityFilterChain` which by default will process all HTTP requests.

When there are multiple `SecurityFilterChain` , it will check each `SecurityFilterChain` one by one in priority order and the first that can process the request will be used.

As both `SecurityFilterChain` are configured to process all HTTP requests , the `SecurityFilterChain` with the higher priority order are always be used.

So simply change the `SecurityFilterChain` for the API to have a higher priority and configure it to process the URL start with the API endpoint :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public static class ApiSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/**");
            //continue configure http ......
        }

}
```

Comment: \@EnableWebSecurity already includes \@Configuration