# <Spring Security> Having OAuth2 and basic authentication in the same application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a SpringBoot application which mainly serves as a web application. It uses OAuth2 (with AzureAD) authentication. Now the scenario is that it also needs to serve as an API provider, which uses basic authentication. So basically default is OAuth2, except for patterns like (/rest/api/**).

Below is my source after doing some searching around.

On testing it exempted the (/rest/api/**) pattern from authentication. I suppose this is casued by the line ".antMatchers("/rest/api/**").permitAll()". But if this line is omitted, suppose the  (/rest/api/**) pattern will be picked up by "WebSecurityAzureConfig" and will require OAuth2 authentication, which is not what is wanted.

Any suggestions and advices are much appreciatd, thank you.

```
package com.test.security;

import com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AzureAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AzureOidcUserService oidcUserService;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class WebSecurityAzureConfig extends AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            super.configure(http);
            http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                    .and()
                        .csrf().disable()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/scripts/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/csrf").permitAll() // Swagger
                        .antMatchers("/version").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/healthCheck").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll() // TODO Remove it before going to PROD
                        .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/oauth/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/rest/api/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                    .and()
                        .oauth2Login()
                        .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .oidcUserService(oidcUserService)
                        .and()
                        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .and()
                        .logout()
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccess")
                        .permitAll();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class WebSecurityBasicConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/api/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Multiple HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity) in the reference docs. You want to flip it so the specific pattern (`http.antMatchers("/rest/api/**")...`) is first.

Comment: Anyone having same requirement may have a look at this related thread as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137201/spring-security-work-only-for-highest-priority-order

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Steve Riesenberg for your  suggestion,

You wan to have the multiple authentication  `(http.antMatchers("/rest/api/**").)` is first executes reference Java [Configuration :: Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity)

Try with adding the a custom authority, let's call it `ROLE_BASICAUTH`, when an user connects using basic auth, and `ROLE_OAUTH2` when an user connects using OAuth2. That way, you can use

```
.antMatchers("/endpoint-that-requires-basic-auth").hasRole("BASICAUTH")
.antMatchers("/endpoint-that-requires-oauth2").hasRole("OAUTH2")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

When they reach an endpoint that you want basic authentication (and not OAuth2), you check their current authorities, and if it's not BASICAUTH, then you invalidate their session you display a login form without OAuth2 (to force them to use the basic authentication).

For more details refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061662/spring-boot-basic-authentication-and-oauth2-in-same-project):